# How can I add configurable variables to my add-on?

Tags: add-on-development, configuration-variables

I have developed a module, and now I would like it to make it configurable by admin users. How do I go about adding editable variables (I assume to the control panel page) and how do I later access these values in my code please?

I can't find any useful tutorials or references on this subject.

Comment: To start: have you read through the [module development tutorial](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html)?

Comment: yes I have, did I miss something?

Comment: Possibly - I'll answer below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules in EE have no built-in way to store configuration data (unlike Extensions, in which you can store "settings").

So you'll have to create your own custom database table(s) during module installation, then write to/fetch from that table in your module control panel methods.

The [module tutorial in the user guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html) shows how to create a new table during install, and also how to fetch data in your .mcp file, then pass that data to your view file.

I'd strongly suggest reading through the entire [add-on development section](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/index.html) of the user guide, it will give you a pretty comprehensive overview of how things work in EE add-on development.